# How to measure fps in c# .net winform

Tags: c#, winforms

How to measure fps in c# WinForms and display it in a label?

I looked in a lot of websites but I can't find a way.

Comment: Do you mean frames per second (fps)?
Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a moment to re-read the guidelines for asking questions here in the [Help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Answer (score 3):

This isn't really how Windows Forms work.  They don't run in a "game loop" like most 3D games do, constantly updating state and redrawing at a regular and measurable rate.  Instead, they have an event loop that is comparatively "empty": most of the time, they're just sitting there, doing nothing.  Redraws only happen in response to controls being changed, which typically only happens on input from the keyboard, mouse, or touch panel.

Comment: so i can't do that ?

Comment: It's not so much that you can't do it as that there is no such thing.  There's no overall "frame rate" in Windows Forms, because a typical Windows Form simply doesn't redraw itself at regular intervals.

Comment: thanks for the help :)